# Rotating the graph of a function.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is to rotate a function f(x) by 90 degrees and obtain a new rotated function g(x). I've tried to use the rotation matrix and the formula g(x,y) =(f(xcos(a) - y sin(o)) - xsin(o) ) / cos(o) and they seem to work, but I don't really end up with a form of g(x).
Is there even a way to do that, because on the internet I only read that the rotated graph isn't a function anymore?

In the attached pictures the problem is visualized. In the first figure the original function f(x) and in the second picture the wished rotated function is shown.

[original function f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dhbP.png) 
[rotated function g(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTY1a.png)

Comment: Could you give the explicit formula for $f(x)$?

Comment: f(x) = -B * (coth(3*x/a) - (a)/(3*x)) + m*x
where B, a and m are real constants. (m and a are typically chosen very small)

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the inverse image of the $y$-axis under your rotation. If any line parallel to $L$ cuts the graph in more than one point, then the resulted rotated points cannot be a function of $x$ anymore after rotation.

Under some circumstances you may get lucky, as you did in the example you posted.

The graph of your function is the set of points $(x,f(x))$, and you can always rotate that with the linear transformation $(x,f(x))\mapsto (\cos(\theta)x+\sin(\theta)f(x), -\sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta)f(x))$, but the resulting set of points is no longer guaranteed to be the graph of a function of $x$.

For example, when you rotate the graph of $f(x)=x^2$ by $\pi/4$ clockwise, you get this graph:

[image]

You can see there on the $y$-axis it cannot be expressed as a function of $x$ alone. You can however express it as a function of a parameter $t$ which outputs ordered pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give your $f(x)$ so it is impossible to be precise, but it appears that $f(x) = -2 \tanh (2 x)$:

[image]

in which the "rotated" version is simply the inverse function (with a minus sign), i.e., $g(x) = 1/2 \tanh^{-1} (x/2)$:

[image]